# Laravel paginate method not working with map collection?

Tags: php, laravel

```
$items = Item::with('product')->paginate(10);

    $items = $items->map(function($product){
          $product->name = "Test";
          return $product; 
    });

    return response()->json(['items' => $items]);
```

In my view blade on console paginate objects not showed?

Comment: Your `items` object is no longer pagination object. You change it with standart collection.

Comment: But how i can change it with standart collection. Please explain with example

Comment: why u converting it to MAP ? can't you just return the paginator instance ?

Comment: Yes I need use map method.I know without map collection paginate is working perfectly, but when I use map collection paginate method not working

Comment: since, `$items` paginator instance is a colection, you should use `foreach` on `$items`

Answer (score 52, accepted):

As, given in [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-transform), `map()` method creates a new collection. To modify the values in the current collection, use `transform()` method.

```
$items->getCollection()->transform(function ($product) {
    $product->name = "Test";
    return $product;
});
```

Also, since, paginator's items are a collection. You can use `foreach` directly on `$items`

```
foreach ($items as $item)
{
 $item->name = "Test";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but this transform method working with('product') relationship?

Comment: is it not working ? I think you might need to see the collection in debug :(. just to see what you are getting at `$product`

Comment: Yes I check all, but when I use transform method working perfectly, I get paginate object elements,  but  you know I get items with product relationship. At my view blade I can't display products elements

Comment: I'm sorry I din't understand the problem :( . You got the `$product` values, right ? but you are getting issue while displaying those values in view ?

Comment: thanks for help, transform method is working perfectly.

Comment: Thanks so much, this is what I looked for.

Comment: I've got undefined method transform in laravel 8

Comment: the foreach worked for me, thanks!

Comment: This worked using transform.

Answer (score 22):

Here's a cleaner way to handle this.

```
$items = Item::with('product')->paginate(10)
        ->through(function($product){
        $product->name = "Test";
        return $product;
    });

    return response()->json(['items' => $items]);
```

Unlike map() which returns a brand new collection, through() applies to the current retrieved items rather than a brand new collection

Answer (score 6):

An easy solution would be to just use `tap()` like so:

```php
return tap(Item::with('product')->paginate(10))->map(...);
```

The `tap()` helper always returns its argument, so you can call any function you like and still return the paginator instance. This is often used in instances like `return tap($user)->save()`, where the `save` function returns a boolean but you still want to return the `$user` object.

Comment: Of all the answers, this one works!

Answer (score 1):

You should save the data in a collection, work on them, inject them back, something like this:

```
$page = Input::get('page', 1);
$data = Item::with('product')->getByPage($page, 10);
$tempItems = $data->items;

$tempItems = $tempItems->map(function($product){
      $product->name = "Test";
      return $product; 
});


$objects = Paginator::make($tempItems, $data->totalItems, 10);
```

Comment: thank you for reply, but I get error Undefined property: Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::$data

Comment: Third line of your code $tempItems = $data->items, here items from where?

Comment: And I have also error.Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getByPage()