# Laravel paginate method not working with transform method

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

When I am using a transform method after calling `paginate(20)` it will return regular results, `without paginating` that is not supposed to be.

and when I remove `transform()` method paginate work as it supposes to be.

```
$users =
    User::whereUser_role(1)
        ->join('user_types', 'users.user_type', '=', 'user_types.user_type_id')
        ->when(request('user-type'), function ($query) {
            $query->where('user_types.name', '=', request('user-type'));
        })
        ->addSelect(
            'users.*',
            'user_types.name as user_type',
        )
        ->orderBy('users.created_at', 'desc')
        ->paginate(20)
        ->appends(request()->all())
        ->getCollection()
        ->transform(function ($user) {
            $user->user_status = $user->status ? "Active" : "InActive";
            $user->email_verified = $user->email_verified ? "Yes" : "No";
            return $user;
        });

$users->makeHidden(['user_role']);

return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Success',
            'status' => 200,
            'requestLocation' => request()->path(),
            'success' => true,
            'data' => $users
        ], 200);
```

Comment: & I am using laravel 5.8 version

Comment: does `map` do the same?

Comment: haven't used it yet. but maybe not working this too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45903926/laravel-paginate-method-not-working-with-map-collection/45904615

Comment: the difference in the accepted answer of that question is the `getCollection` that comes before the `transform`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `getCollection` method for the same. As per laravel API documentaion:

> `getCollection()` : Get the paginator's underlying collection.

For e.g.

```
$users = User::whereStatus(1)
          ->paginate(20);


// iterates paginated items and applies a transformation 
$users->getCollection()->transform(function ($user) {
    $user->email_verified = $user->email_verified ? "Yes" : "No";
    return $user;
})
```

Reference:[Laravel API -> AbstractPaginator -> getCollection()](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Pagination/AbstractPaginator.html#method_getCollection)

Comment: What result are you getting using getCollection?

Comment: simple results. nothing was changed when I used this method.

Comment: @Dipen I generated the same scenario and it is working fine at my end.

Comment: thanks for your efforts. but see here I updated question. where i am using ```where```, ```when``` conditions as well ```appends()``` and ```makeHidden()``` method.